# postgresql, selección del máximo de un count

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy en clase haciendo un trabajo de sql, y me piden que seleccione el nombre del médico que más recetas de ibuprofeno y que su especialidad no sea de pediatría, me sale resultado correcto, pero me salen todos los nombres junto con su resultado, en vez de escoger el máximo, alguien tiene alguna idea?

esta es la select que tengo:

```
    Select inst1.name, max(receptes)
from doctor, prescription, (select name, doctor.doc_number, count(presc_number) as "receptes"
                from prescription, doctor
                where prescription.doc_number = doctor.doc_number and drug like 'Ibuprofè' and specialty not like 'Pediatria'
                group by doctor.name, doctor.doc_number) as inst1
where doctor.doc_number = prescription.doc_number
group by inst1.name
```

Answer (score 3):

Primero que todo, hay varios puntos mejorables en tu consulta. Por ejemplo, `LIKE` se usa típicamente cuando quieres hacer match en parte del contenido, y para eso se usan "wildcards" (`%`). Sin esos wildcards, es casi idéntico a usar `=`. Me da la impresión que para la droga puedes usar `LIKE`, pero para la especialidad usar `=`.

Por otro lado, no necesitas obtener la "prescription" en la consulta, eso sólo ayuda a enredar un poco el código que estás utilizando.

También te recomiendo encarecidamente que no uses joins implícitos, ya que están deprecados, usa siempre joins explícitos.

Otra recomendación es que uses alias en las tablas y evites usar subquerys que no son necesarias.

Dicho lo anterior, mi consulta sería de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  d.doctor,
        COUNT(DISTINCT p.presc_number) as "receptes"
FROM doctor d
INNER JOIN prescription p
    ON d.doc_number = p.doc_number
WHERE p.drug LIKE 'Ibuprofè%'
AND d.specialty <> 'Pediatria'
GROUP BY d.doctor
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT p.presc_number) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás preguntando dos veces por lo mismo. La salida de esa consulta podrías obtenerla con

```
select name, 
       count(presc_number) as receptes
from prescription join doctor on prescription.doc_number = doctor.doc_number
where drug like 'Ibuprofè' 
  and specialty not like 'Pediatria'
group by doctor.name, doctor.doc_number 
ORDER BY count(presc_number) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Además sospecho que no necesitas el operador `like` sino una igualdad.

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero lo que necesito es que devuelva únicamente el valor máximo del count junto con el nombre asociado y es ahí donde estoy atascado...

Comment: He encontrado la solución, en cuanto pueda la cuelgo!